# Is this an issue with PyQt?

Tags: pyqt4, ros

I'm using Gazebo ROS simulator and when I try to open it, it just crashes with the following error messages reported.

[image: Gazebo Error Log]

I have another application that uses PyQt4 and that one runs smoothly without any errors, but since this gazebo error log has qt4 references, could this be of an error caused by an issue in PyQt4 libraries? I tried to reinstall PyQt4 but the issue still persists.

Any insight into this matter would be highly appreciated. Thanks! :)

**Specs**:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Gazebo 7
- ROS Kinetic

PS:
When I run gzclient with verbose tag, it crashes and gives the same error stack.

```
$ gzclient --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.14.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.102
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
$
```

However gzserver stays up;

```
$ gzserver --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.14.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.1.102
```

Comment: Please run gzserver and gzclient in standalone mode one after another with debug flags! Does the error still occure?

Comment: Hi @Tik0 ! I've added a PS part to my question with additional text I get when gzserver and gzclient is executed